# ERROR - AuthenticationAdmin System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : POST_AUTHENTICATION

Tags: wso2-api-manager

After enabling locking account in wso2 api manager 3.2.0, when I try to login to /carbon by admin user I faced following exception :

```
 ERROR - AuthenticationAdmin System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User : Error when handling event : POST_AUTHENTICATION
```

Comment: Is this admin user in the JDBC user store or LDAP/AD userstore?

Comment: Yes, that's admin user